# $img_attributes style question

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error

**Can somebody explain me why the small piece of code doesn't work?**

This is the error what is given:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /var/www/g35003/

```
$img_attributes= style='max-height: 100px; max-width: 100px' . 'alt="'.$product['product_name'].'"';
```

Comment: I didn't see any references to javascript *or* resizing in your question so I removed those tags and added the PHP tag.  Tagging is an important aspect of SO, so please try and make sure you choose tags relevant to your question so that they reach the correct experts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is PHP and you are trying to assign a string to a variable, there should be quotes arround the string.

Here, this specific portion of code is causing an error :

```
$img_attributes= style='max
```

There should be some kind of quote after the first = sign.

Something like this should work much better, for instance :

```
$img_attributes= 'style="max-height: 100px; max-width: 100px"'
     . ' alt="' . $product['product_name'] . '"';
```

---

As a sidenote : maybe some kind of escaping could be helpful, for the `$product['product_name']` part ? to make sure it doesn't contain any HTML that would break your markup.

See [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars), for instance.

For instance, if your product name is initialized this way :

```
$product['product_name'] = 'my mega "product"';
```

Then, using the portion of code I posted earlier will get you this output :

```
style="max-height: 100px; max-width: 100px" alt="my mega "product""
```

Which is not that nice...

Using `htmlspecialchars`, like this :

```
$img_attributes= 'style="max-height: 100px; max-width: 100px"'
     . ' alt="' . htmlspecialchars($product['product_name']) . '"';
```

The output would become :

```
style="max-height: 100px; max-width: 100px" alt="my mega &quot;product&quot;"
```

Which, at least, is a portion of valid-HTML :-)

Comment: +1 for (sadly all-too-rare) correct usage of htmlspecialchars. I'm not sure `alt` is the best place for a product name though. Perhaps `title` would be more appropriate?

Comment: That would be better for SEO right?

@ Pascal, thank you very much, good explanation.

Comment: @Chris : you're welcome :-) ;; @bobince : well, maybe (except for the fact that alt is required, and title is not -- so, if you only have one information, why not put it in alt ? but it's another question ^^ )

Answer (score 2):

You are messing the quotes, possible fix:

```
$img_attributes= "style='max-height: 100px; max-width: 100px'" . 'alt="'.$product['product_name'].'"';
```